# Want to know Maven project structure

Tags: maven

i m working on a maven project and i want to know the basic structure of it. I know that there is a pom.xml that defines artifacts involved in the project. But in my project, there are 5 pom.xml. So i want to know what is the exact role of pom and how do we handle dependencies.

Appreciate if anyone can suggest any useful book or resource which can guide.

Regards
Anurag

Comment: Show us some pom's. Normally, there is one pom for each project.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its a java project the basic structure is:

```
Parent Dir
-src/main/java/        java source files for the application (included in the JAR/WAR)
-src/main/resourcs/    resource files, xml, properties, etc (included in the JAR/WAR)
-src/test/java/        java source files for tests (only used during testing)
-src/test/resources/   resource files for testing (only used during testing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Sonatype's "Maven: The Definitive Guide" (also known as "Maven By Example"). The book is available for free from their site, or you can buy it.

Comment: thanks for suggestion ...  i think is should probably study the basic first

Comment: This is the best book on Maven out there as it's written by the people who made Maven. Their site seems currently down for maintenance, but I'm sure you can still find the book somewhere (while it's down) or buy it online. You can't just get Maven like that without doing some proper reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html and I can recommend the book "Maven by Example: Table of Contents / Documentation Sonatype". 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the links to know more about POM

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_pom.htm